# software for kids where they can play games and browse internet

Tags: c++, user-interface, webbrowser-control, gecko, rapid-prototyping

I'm trying to build a simple utility for kids where they can play games and browse the internet.

this is the final product i need to come up with:

- cross platform
- a gui
- with an web browser in it.
- which can open other applications like games in a window(say 600X400)
  instead of the whole screen (is it possible to open    applications
  from a click of a button in a window?)
- which has a timer, that clocks down and then disables everything
  (games and browser)

what is the best way that i can go about. i'm good at c++ (jut c++ i know nothing of COM, ...)

i've been thinking of U++ as my gui framework. I thought of using Gecko to integrate browser in gui, but that seems pretty complex any thing easy?

Comment: Opening applications that want to be full-screen in a window isn't going to be an easy task at all. And having the timer "disable" everything (if that includes arbitrary third party apps) will be quite difficult if you mean something other than 'kill' by 'disable'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QT is the easiest existing GUI library solution for multiplatform applications like the one you need. And it's easy to "have web browser" capabilities due to very nice integration with [WebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit)

See the [QT page](http://qt.nokia.com/) here

Comment: Agreed and will change the answer

Comment: As he already knows C++, Qt seems like a good mesh. It's trivially easy to integrate WebKit into an app via QtWebKit (unlike Gecko into... anything), and can help with most of his requirements.